# How does JavaScript detect regular expressions?

Tags: javascript, regex, parsing

I am writing a JS parser, and am wondering how to differentiate between a regular expression (`/lookup/g`) and simple division (`bar/baz/g`). What are the rules that JavaScript uses to identify regular expressions?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You want to check out [Section 7.8.5](http://es5.github.com/#x7.8.5) in the ECMA spec (the annotated version is up-to-date currently, but always check the [latest PDF from the ECMA](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/Ecma-262.pdf)).

Remember too that a JavaScript regex can not be empty. `//` is *always* the start of a single line comment. It's also worth mentioning that a semicolon must never be inserted before a regex literal.

Tangential, an *empty* JavaScript regex looks like `/(?:)/`.

[Further discussion](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-HK/jscript/thread/0286c8cc-efdd-4b0b-999b-5591b999d620).

Comment: Note that the grammar appears to have changed a bit in the [latest version](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/Ecma-262.pdf).

Comment: @AndrewMarshall: I would of linked that if it were in HTML format - do you know if one exists? Thanks.

Comment: Yea that's why I figured you'd linked to that version instead. And no I don't, unfortunately. I just wanted to add the link to the latest version for completeness sake.

Comment: @alex: [Here](http://es5.github.com/#x7.8.5) is the link again. I deleted the comment by accident (don't ask).